# Ipv6: Are Link-Local adresses static?

Tags: networking, dns, ipv6

Every nic will autogenerate its own Link-Local Ipv6 address. From what I see on my computers, this address is created by the Link-Local prefix 'fe80::' and the MAC address (obfuscated).
The question is: Is this address STATIC (meaning it will never change)?
I ask because I have a local DNS running and want to make a local Network with 2 servers, that are only meant to be reached from the LAN.

**Update:**

I have found out that the Link-Local address in Windows actually does change at rare occcasions - for instance when updating the NIC's driver, so it's not totally static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether the link local address is static depends on the operating system. If you can see it's derived from the MAC address then it's probably static.

However, you can't use link local addresses in DNS. Link local addresses are not globally unique and can't be routed. If you want to use IPv6 then get global addresses from your ISP or generate a block of ULA addresses for private use.

Comment: I already use a local dns for my custom domain with Ipv4 private addresses (they don't need to be routable or global). I want to do the same with Ipv6.

Comment: Then use ULA. Link local addresses are not usable for your purpose

Comment: I can't edit Ip adresses on my phone, on my nas I can only enter 1 address (which must be global) and I can't control Ip addresses on my router either.

Answer (score 1):

For an private ipv6 network like an private ipv4 (for example the 10.0.0.0/8) you must use ipv6 ula fc00::/7 adresses, a router can route these adresses only in an LAN environment.
Fe80::/10 adresses can only used between two physical links or in an switched network. (Like the apipa adresses 169.254.0.0/16 in ipv4).

Comment: I can open my nas' web interface by typing the LINK-LOCAL address! So that Works.